# How to have ItemsControl wrap vertically and scroll horizontally

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am able to do this using a `ListView` like this.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="..."
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <callistoControls:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Title}" Command="..." CommandParameter="..."  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I don't need all the features of a `ListView` though. I'd rather just items an `ItemsControl` instead of turning off all the unwanted features in the `ListView` by re-doing the templates/etc.

How can I achieve this with an `ItemsControl`?

Comment: What you're looking for seems to be a `GridView`. If you want to do it with an `ItemsControl` or `ListView`, the key is the `WrapPanel` that you have set for the `ItemsPanel`. Built in is a `WrapGrid` and `VariableSizedWrapGrid` which have similar functionality.

Comment: I don't want all of the extra features like highlighting the item on hover. I would have to change the visual states of a `GridView` or `ListView` if I used them.

Comment: Good point. Jerry's answer is a good option then.

Comment: Yes, I will give it a try as soon as I'm able to. I swear I tried that exact configuration before, but maybe not. I was messing with it for a while, so I probably missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<ScrollViewer 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="...">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <callistoControls:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Best of luck.

Comment: This works perfectly. I swear I tried every combination, but I must have missed something. Thanks!